# ATP Hydrolysis to AMP in the Urea Cycle. What is the Free Energy Change?

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, amino-acids

How is the hydrolysis of ATP into AMP and PPi in making arginosuccinate equivalent to the hydrolysis of 2 ATP?

Comment: Please provide a source for the statement you are querying. This will provide a context for us to interpret it and provide an appropriate answer. @user1136 had provided a comprehensive quantitative answer, but I wonder if your original source is making a more general qualitative point. At the moment your question is unclear and is likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, I reckon, is that *as stated* it isn't.

**However,the hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> yields considerable more free energy than does the hydrolysis of ATP into ADP and P<sub>i</sub>**.

That is, the free energy change for the hydrolysis of  ATP into AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> is considerably more negative that that for the hydrolysis of ATP into ADP and P<sub>i</sub> *and* for the hydrolysis of ADP into AMP and P<sub>i</sub>.

If we consider the the free energy change for the reaction ATP  = AMP + 2 P<sub>i</sub>  (where, say, the pyrophosphate (PP<sub>i</sub>) produced by  [argininosuccinate synthetase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argininosuccinate_synthase) is broken down by a  pyrophosphatase), then  it *is* the equivalent to  the  hydrolysis of 2 ATP to ADP and P<sub>i</sub> and (more or less) to  the hydrolysis of 2 ADP to AMP and P<sub>i</sub>.

When dealing with ATP hydrolysis, we must take the 'chemical environment' of the phosphate group into account, not only in determining whether the bond is 'high energy' (in the [Lipmann](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/medicine/laureates/1953/lipmann-bio.html) sense) or 'low energy', but also when considering the amount of free energy released by hydrolysis of a  'high energy' linkage: not all pyrophosphate linkages yield the same free energy on hydrolysis.

> - Cleavage of the 'inner' pyrophosphate linkage in ATP (to give AMP and PP<sub>i</sub>) 'releases' considerably more free energy than cleavage of this linkage in ADP (to give ADP and P<sub>i</sub>).
> - Cleavage of the 'inner' pyrophosphate linkage in ATP  (to give AMP and PP<sub>i</sub>) releases considerable more free energy than the cleavage of the 'outer' pyrophosphate linkage (to give ADP and P<sub>i</sub>).

If  one 'unit' of free energy is considered to be about 32 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> then:

- The hydrolysis of ATP to ADP and ADP *roughly* releases 1 unit
- The hydrolysis of ADP to P<sub>i</sub> and AMP roughly releases 1 unit
- **The hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> *roughly* releases about 1.4 units**
- The hydrolysis of PP<sub>i</sub> to 2 P<sub>i</sub> *roughly* releases about  0.6 units
- Hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and 2 P<sub>i</sub> *roughly* releases 2 units.
- Hydrolysis of AMP to adenosine and P<sub>i</sub> *roughly* releases 0.4
  units.

> **The question posed by the OP may now be answered as follows**.
>
> Hydrolysis the inner pyrophosphate linkage of ATP (to give AMP) rather than the outer linkage (to give ADP) provides a 'thermodynamic pull' of 0.4 'free energy units' to the  [argininosuccinate synthase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argininosuccinate_synthase) reaction.  If the  PP<sub>i</sub> is hydrolyzed by a pyrophosphatase an extra 0.6 'free energy units' are obtained and the free energy change for the combined reaction (that of [argininosuccinate synthase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argininosuccinate_synthase) and the pyrophosphatase) is equivalent to 2 'free energy units' (about -70 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>).

As pointed out by [Frey, & Arabshahi (1995)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw), hydrolysis of the $\alpha$,$\beta$-phosphoanhydride of ATP, rather than the $\beta$,$\gamma$ linkage, is a common strategy in biosynthetic reactions.  To quote the final line of this paper: *Cleavage of the $\beta$,$\gamma$-phosphoanhydride bridge in ATP takes place in metabolic reactions in which a smaller driving force is required.*

**A Small Piece of History**

It was not always accepted that the hydolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> proceeded with a more negative free energy than for the hydrolysis of ATP to ADP and P<sub>i</sub>.  To quote from  [Standard Free Energy Change for the Hydrolysis of the $\alpha, \beta$-Phosphoanhydride Bridge in ATP](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw) , by Frey & Arabshahi (1995).

> It  appears to be common knowledge in biochemistry  that the standard free energy change $\Delta G^{'o}$ for the hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> is -7.7   to  -8.4 kcal  mol<sup>-1</sup> [-32 to -35 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>].  Most textbooks of biochemistry  list  values  in  this  range (Zubay, 1993; Lehninger et al.,  1992; Garrett & Grisham, 1994; Voet & Voet, 1990; Matthews & Van  Holde, 1990). Moreover, many  textbooks  also  list  the standard free energy  for  the hydrolysis of  PP<sub>i</sub> as  $\Delta G^{'o}$ = - 7.9 to  8.0 kcal  mol<sup>-1</sup>.  [-33 to -33.5 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>]. However,  the  true  value for pyrophosphate  hydrolysis is significantly less negative (Flodgaard & Fleron, 1974). Therefore, the standard free energy change for the hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> must be more negative  than 8 kcal  mol<sup>-1</sup> [ 33.5 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>]  as is explained in this paper

This reminder should not have been necessary.  The correct value for the free energy change in the hydrolysis of ATP to AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> is given by [Schuegraf et al (1960)](http://www.jbc.org/content/235/12/3597.full.pdf)  , a paper co-authored by [Sarah Ratner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Ratner)

**The hydrolysis of UDP-Glucose**

$\Delta G^{'o}$ for the hydrolysis of UDP-glucose to UMP and  glucose-1-phosphate is about - 43 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (- 10.3 mol<sup>-1</sup>) [[Frey, & Arabshahi, 1995](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw)], also considerably more negative that that for the hydrolysis of ATP into ADP and P<sub>i</sub>

**Specifics**

- The standard free energy of hydrolysis ($\Delta G^{'o}$) of the $\alpha$,$\beta$-phosphoanhydride of ATP to give AMP and PP<sub>i</sub> is about - 45 to -50 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis of the $\alpha$,$\beta$-phosphoanhydride of ADP to give ADP and P<sub>i</sub> is about -30 to -34 kJ/mol
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis of the $\beta$,$\gamma$-phosphoanhydride of ATP to give ADP and P<sub>i</sub> is about -32 to -36 kJ/mol.
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis ($\Delta G^{'o}$) of PP<sub>i</sub> to 2 P<sub>i</sub> is about 20 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis ATP to AMP an 2P<sub>i</sub> about -70 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>.
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis ($\Delta G^{'o}$) of PP<sub>i</sub> to 2 P<sub>i</sub> is about 20 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- The standard free energy of hydrolysis ATP to AMP an 2P<sub>i</sub> about -70 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>.

(For a diagram illustrating the  nomenclature of the $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ phosphates of ATP, see [here](https://bio.libretexts.org/LibreTexts/University_of_California_Davis/BIS_2A%3A_Introductory_Biology_(Britt)/Readings/W2017_Lecture_12_reading)).

**Notes**

- Following [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x), all equations are written as 'biochemical equations' where everything is balanced except hydrogen ions.
- $\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -50 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-12 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ ATP + H_2O= AMP +PP_i $$

- [1 ]  [Frey, & Arabshahi (1995)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw) give a value of -45.6 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-10.9 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [2] [Dixon et al  (2000)](http://www.jbc.org/content/275/21/15828.full.pdf) give a value of  -48.5 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-11.6 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [3] [Schuegraf et al (1960)](http://www.jbc.org/content/235/12/3597.full.pdf)  give a value of  -43 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-10.3 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [4 ] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1) of -50.2 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-12.0 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

---

- $\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -36 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-12 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ ATP + H_2O= ADP +P_i    $$

- [1] [Frey, & Arabshahi (1995)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw) give a value of -32.6 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-7.8 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [2] [Rosing & Slater, 1972](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0005272872901168) give a value of -31.5 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-7.53 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [3] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1 ) of -36.6 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-8.8 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

---

- $\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -34 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-8.1 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ ADP + H_2O= AMP +P_i $$

- [1] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1) of -34.04 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-8.13 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

---

- $\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -71, kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-16.9 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ ATP + 2 H_2O = AMP + P_i  + P_i$$

- [1] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1) of -70.68 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-16.9 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

---

$\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -13.7 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-3.3 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ AMP+ H_2O  =  Adenosine  +P_i $$

- [1] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1) of -13.74 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-3.28 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

---

- $\Delta G^{o'}$ for the following reaction is about -20.5 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-4.9 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)

$$ PP_i + H_2O= P_i +P_i $$

- [1] [Frey, & Arabshahi (1995)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00036a001?journalCode=bichaw) give a value of -19.24 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-4.6 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>).
- [2] Calculation from the tables supplied by [Alberty (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) gives a value (25<sup>o</sup>C, pH 7, ionic strength of 0.1) of -20.5kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> (-4.9 kcal mol<sup>-1</sup>)